# Why does this formula to return the average the top n% return an error for some values?

Tags: excel-formula

In another thread here the suggestion was made to use:

-AVERAGEIF(A2:A10,">"&PERCENTILE(A2:A10,0.7))

to return the average of the top n% of the values in the specified range.

This seems to work most, but not all, of the time.

For example if I start with a column of twenty empty cells and insert 75,69,75,56,75,73 as the first six values,

the formula returns a #DIV/0! error for .8, but not .7.

However, changing the leading 75 to 74 returns a non-error result for either  .7 or .8 .

Our of around 40 instances of use in a sheet, this was the only set of inputs that returned an error.

Is this the correct behavior of this construction when evaluating properly, or a problem in Excel?

---

Igrore - I can't get the values in the question to formated properly.

Comment: I can't reproduce your error, can you show a screen shot of the sheet and the specific formula when it errors.  You will need to upload the photo to imugr and link it in the original post.

Comment: I have the error scott.  Running 2013.  I have tried it both horizontal and vertical

Comment: @ForwardEd i am too, what exactly did you do?

Comment: I copied his string from the question and pasted it into a cell, then did a text to columns, choosing comma and a bunch of other stuff I had left over from previous runs with ignore repeat delineators.  I then just retyped his formula and pooff div/0.

Comment: now admittedly I have something else wonky going on from an earlier paste issue and I dont think Civilization 5 is helping out matters any either.  I currently cant see formulas in the formula bar and its ticking me off.

Comment: I tried the data in both horizontal and vertical configuration and both give the same error.  I tried entering it as a CSE but that is where I dont know if it did it or not as my formula bar is on the fritz.

Comment: All numbers are numbers as the are in the right portion of the cell....did you use percentile compatibility for pre 2007 or one of the other percentile?

Comment: Did you put the values in one row?  I put twenty empty rows in column A  and the numbers in the next six rows. then in using the formula `=AVERAGEIF(A1:A26,">"&PERCENTILE(A1:A26,0.8))` I got 79.  seehttp://imgur.com/LDfCtNv

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112700/discussion-between-forward-ed-and-scott-craner).

Comment: The reason is that the percentile on those numbers is returning 75 and there are no numbers greater than that.  Change the `>` to `>=` and you should avoid the error.

Comment: The change to ">=" did indeed solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

The reason its failing on you is that the  70th percentile of the 6 numbers you have choosen is 75.  As such when you go through your data there is no number greater than 75.  so you wind up with an empty array.

I am not a stats person but one potential solution would be to change the > to >=  in which case it would grab all number also equal to the 70th percentile.  If that is not acceptable you could wrap the whole thing in an IFFERROR formula:

```
=IFERROR(YOUR FORMULA,"nothing greater than the X percentile")
```

So in your case it is merely a special case where all the number in the array were equal or less then your cut off point.  Changing the 75 to 74 changes the result of the 70th percentile.